# How to get nested array data on AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, model, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have no clue how to fetch nested data on AppSync with React.
These are the models.

```
type BlrPost @model {
  id: ID!
  parentId: String!
  parent: BlrParent @connection(name: "ParentPost")
  title: String
  contents: String
  tags: [String]
  ask: Float
  urgentFlg: Boolean
  Bids: [BlrBid] @connection(name: "PostBids")
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}

type BlrBid @model {
  id: ID!
  price: Float!
  duration: Int!
  Post: BlrPost @connection(name: "PostBids")
  consultation: BlrConsultation @connection(name: "BidConsultation")
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

I want to fetch Bids data details in BlrPost with below code.

```
const postsData = await API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(listBlrPosts, {
    sortDirection: 'ASC'
  })
);
```

However, I can fetch nextToken only.

```
...
Bids:
nextToken: null
__proto__: Object
...
```

I can fetch other data. And also, if I try this on AWS console directly, I can get Bids data like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it. All I have to do is adding information that I need on `listBlrPosts` in  `graphql/queries.` Like this.

[Before]

```
export const listBlrPosts = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListBlrPosts(
    $filter: ModelBlrPostFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listBlrPosts(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        parentId
        parent {
          id
          cognitoId
          nickname
          email
          phone
          zip
          imgUrlS3
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        title
        contents
        tags
        ask
        urgentFlg
        Bids {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`
```

[After]

```
export const listBlrPosts = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListBlrPosts(
    $filter: ModelBlrPostFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listBlrPosts(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        parentId
        parent {
          id
          cognitoId
          nickname
          email
          phone
          zip
          imgUrlS3
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        title
        contents
        tags
        ask
        urgentFlg
        Bids {
          items {
            id
            price
            duration
            createdAt
            updatedAt
          }
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Yes, but isn't nextToken there for a reason so you can get paginated data for your nested array?